# Cannot access hdfs file system running in mapr sandbox VM

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, virtualbox, mapr

I have just installed the MapR sandbox virtual machine running in Virtualbox. The VM is set up using "NAT" network mode and ports are forwarded to my Mac. Since the ports are forwarded I am guessing that I should be able to access the hdfs on "localhost".

now I am trying to list the contents of the hdfs on the VM:

```
$ hadoop fs -fs maprfs://localhost -ls /
15/03/25 15:16:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where    applicable
2015-03-25 15:16:11,6646 ERROR Cidcache fs/client/fileclient/cc/cidcache.cc:1586 Thread: 4548153344 MoveToNextCldb: No CLDB entries, cannot run, sleeping 5 seconds!
2015-03-25 15:16:16,6683 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/client.cc:813 Thread: 4548153344 Failed to initialize client for cluster localhost:7222, error Connection refused(61)
ls: Could not create FileClient
```

I also tried with 127.0.0.1, with sudo and with the port :5660 at the end without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did not get it to run using the NAT network mode. Instead I had to delete that network adapter including its routing rules. Instead I added an ordinary host-only adapter, which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from NAT network mode to host only fixed the problem. Then, of course I have to use the IP of the VM for accessing maprfs.

Answer (score -1):

if you are just running **plain Spark on local/single node** then you dont need HDFS, you can just mention your input and output files to be loaded from local file system, like below:

```
file:///pathtoinput
file:///pathtooutput
```